# change a variable in socket.on

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to do a project with node.js, but I met a problem displaying a variable.

This part of the code on the client side:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000');
    var a = 0;
    var b = 0;

    socket.on('request', function (data) {
        a = data;
    });

    socket.on('read', function (data) {
        b = data;
    });

    var q = a * b;
    $('span#calculate').html(q);

    // Etc...
});
```

Normally it should display the result of this calculation, but it still displays a `0` (that means the variable has not changed in `socket.on`).

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to the world of asynchronous code! Where nothing runs linearly.

The code you have there is just *adding listeners for events `read` and `request`*, not actually changing `a` and `b`. Therefore, `a` and `b` are still `0` until the handlers are executed, which would be when the server sends over the `read` or `request` events.

What you can do is to place whatever you want to happen after the events fire in a function. Then call that function in the event handlers:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000');
  var a = 0;
  var b = 0;
  var calculate = $('span#calculate');

  function recalculate(q) {

    calculate.html(q);

    //more...    
  }

  socket.on('request', function (data) {
    a = data;
    recalculate(a * b);
  });

  socket.on('read', function (data) {
    b = data;
    recalculate(a * b);
  });

});
```